# What exactly is the job of the Time Masters and how do they do it?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, legends-of-tomorrow

In the TV Show legends of tomorrow the Time Masters are introduced as some kind of time police and preserver of the time line.
To do this, they must be able to detect changes to the timeline (before they affect them) and they must then travel to the time the change was made and revert it (or travel further back and prevent the change) or whatever.

In the show every second episode the main characters screw up the timeline and have to repair it. Gideon forecasts how the future would look like, if they don't.
Shouldn't the screwed up timeline be noticed by the time masters of the future and shouldn't they do their job to pevent or revert the change?
So why does not every time the main characters screw up the timeline a team of time masters appear and try to stop them? Do our main characters repair the damage before the time masters in the future can notice?
Rip Hunter implies that if they cannot repair the timeline until a specific event occurs, the change will be permanent. If this is true and happens before the time masters in the future can notice, how are they supposed to do their job?

And by the way, if they are a police force (with fighting skills like Rip Hunter demonstrates) why do they send bounty hunters instead of - well - time masters?

Comment: How do they do it? *Not very carefully.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the Time Masters are more focused on preventing time aberrations, rather than fixing them. Their focus is stopping time criminals, not fixing the damage done by them. This is why, instead of sending people to fix the changes made by the legends, they send agents to kill them, without impacting the timeline.

The reason why they don't bother to fix time affirmations, is because they have a machine that can manipulate time. Therefore, this pretty much ensure that whatever ripple effects are created by time criminals, will fade in time

Comment: That they have this machine is a secret and only revealed later in the season. It is unknown to the lower ranks of the time masters (like Rip Hunter). So what did they tell those lower ranks is their job? What was the typical working day of Rip Hunter before he started his own mission?

Comment: @Hothie rip did say that his primary job was to capture time criminals I saw him at him as a less extreme version of what they turned Heatwave into.